# Global DataContex declaration

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql

In my service interface I declare `DataClasses1DataContext data = new DataClasses1DataContext();` inside each method. Can I declare it once and make accessible for all methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store it as an instance variable in your class:

```
public class SomeClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly DataClasses1DataContext _context;
    public SomeClass()
    {
        _context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    }

    public void Dispose();
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    public void Method1();
    {
        // You can use the _context here
    }

    public void Method2();
    {
        // You can use the _context here
    }

    ... 
}
```

Now you can use the `context` field in all methods of the class. Bear in mind though that the DbContext should be short living. You should avoid storing it in some static fields. The best approach is to have a DbContext per HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. By having a static property that controls the lifetime of the exposed datacontext, you can have it declared once but still created for a specific period of time. In particular, creating one context per http request (if you host the service in IIS) is a good idea, much better than creating instances everywhere.

I've blogged on that years ago.

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2010/12/container-based-pseudosingletons-in.html

Yet more advanced approach would be to use an IoC container and have your datacontext created and injected automatically upon service creation by the IoC infrastructure. Take a look at yet another one of my tutorials

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/02/lifetime-management-of-wcf-services.html